# Symfony routing: match anything after first node

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'd like to do something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("^/secured") <-- this would not work, just an example
 */
public function securedAction(){
  //return secured JS frontend 
}
```

and have symfony match any routes (`.com/secured/something`; `.com/secured/anything/else`) to this one action without defining all the routes manually.

Does symfony support this? I can't think of the terms to search for this.

How can I match and route to this controller action without defining all routes manually, based off the first node (`/secured`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Route("/secured/{anything}", name="_secured", defaults={"anything" = null}, requirements={"anything"=".+"})
 */

public function securedAction($anything){
    //return secured JS frontend 
}
```

`name` - just name of the route.

`defaults` - here you can set default value of the parameter, if you not provide parameter in the url: `/secured/`

`requirements` - requirements for parameter(s), in this case `anything` can contain forward slash: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html , but you must handle it in your controller action yourself:

for example if you provide url: `/secured/anything/another_thing/one_more_thing`

you can get all parameters by `explode('/', $anything);`

and the results will be:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "anything"
  1 => "another_thing"
  2 => "one_more_thing" ]
```

Just everything after `/secured/` will be one parameter `$anything`.

Comment: I'm about to try this out, can you explain a bit what's going on here?

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.